# Another ACER ELAN i2c Touchpad not working request for ideas

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, acer, aspire

Installed the latest (as of two weeks ago) 20.04 as a dual boot.
Tried many solutions found online, none work, and many seem to have parts of the puzzle already installed that I do not see (like seeing i2c or ELAN in Ubuntu). Have done about 6 re-installs to clean up any mess I make from trying old fixes.
My old (dying) Dell Vostro works as expected, but has the Synoptics touch pad.

1. Acer Laptop Aspire 5 A515-56-76J1
2. Win 10 Home OEM install, the touchpad works.
3. BIOS has no touchpad option
4. WIN 10 shows ELAN I2C filter Driver, 04/22/2020, VER 13.1.181
5. In Ubuntu, Blacklist does not have i2c_i801
6. cat, xinput, and some others do not see I2C, ELAN, or touchpad. Did some compares with the Dell, and I do not see anything related to the touchpad on the ACER but I do on the Dell.
7. Last attempt was modifying GRUB (phethost's video). Also tried a lot from the 16.0X era.

Is there a solution that might help given that I do not see the things others seem to before they find a fix?

Ray, a lost novice

Comment: If you don't tell us exactly what you've already tried, you're not very likely to get different ideas!

Comment: Well, over half of  I have tried said either to set the bios touchpad to normal and/or look for the touchpad using the commands cat and xinput (can not find). I also tried GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="some-other=option i8042.nopnp" and a couple of variants on that, and 1033033/elantech-touchpad-does-not-work-i2c-hid?rq=1.  Problem is, most of these solutions are 3-5+ years old and I think UBUNTU has changed a bit, I am beginning to think that one article on this site (my interpretation) may have a point, if you get it to work for you, you are lucky.  Oh well, may have to give up on this and use M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!  Did an update today and it added the drivers for the Elan touchpad on my machine.  A brief set of testing showed only normal basic mouse functions, but the touchpad works, which means I can now continue to use this as my main travel computer (assuming we can start traveling soon).